# STM32, VSCode, Debug можно ли смотреть значения глобальных переменных в реальном времени?

Tags: visual-studio-code, отладка, stm32, stm32cubeide

Собрал проект на STM32 в VS Code. Все круто, только не устраивает отладка. Значение глобальной переменной видно только если поставить точку останова (breakpoint). Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы оно было видно в реальном времени? Keil и STM32CubeIDE позволяют это делать. Сейчас с проектом работаю в двух средах: в VS Code пишу, а в STM32CubeIDE дебажу. Из расширений установлены Cortex-Debug, SVD Viewer.

[image: Cube ide отлично показывает]

[image: VS code только по точке останова]